# Tiny MCE and Django

Tags: javascript, django, tinymce, tinymce-plugins, django-tinymce

I was trying to build a blogging website. I used Tiny MCE and Django for the purpose.
I could add/upload photos to my blogs. But the problem is **the images uploaded via Tiny MCE** are not responsive for smaller screens like a mobile phone screen. The texts are well responsive but the images **are overflown**. I went through Tiny MCE documentation but didn't find the answer.
Here's my set of code:

## tinyinject.js:

(I am not so good with JS)

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);
script.onload = function () {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#id_content',
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink link image imagetools lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
            'table emoticons template paste help'
        ],
        toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ' +
            'bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | ' +
            'forecolor backcolor emoticons | help | image',
        imagetools_toolbar: "rotateleft rotateright | flipv fliph | editimage imageoptions",
        image_title: true,
        automatic_upload: true,
        file_picker_types: 'image',
        file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
            input.onchange = function() {
                var file = this.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function() {
                    var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                    var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                    var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                    blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                    cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), {title: file.name});
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            };
            input.click();
        },
        menu: {
            favs: { title: 'My Favorites', items: 'code visualaid | searchreplace | emoticons' }
        },
        menubar: 'favs file edit view insert format tools table help',
    });
}
```

> Help needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get responsive images you need to stop TinyMCE from adding pixel widths and height to the inserted images. One way to do that is to use `image_dimensions: false`. Then you use css to set the width of images, a common way is using `img { width: 100%; max-width: 600px; }` where `600px` would be the maximum image width. [Here is a more complex TinyMCE demo](https://tinymce.github.io/tinymce-demos/images/toggle-image-size-context-toolbar.html) if you would like to deep dive into image styling